# How to read another user outlook 365 mail in c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, office365, office365api, o365rwsclient

I have integrated an asp.net web application with office 365 mail using o365 api client library.I have a specific requirement, suppose I have stored the o365 mail id of other users in my database.The o365 mail username/ password also stored in my local database. Is there any way to see the other user's mail details using the mail id/ credentials?
If anybody has any idea please share.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is using OAuth code flow , it seems that only allow access to mail, calendar and contacts belonging to the authenticated user . You may use [OAuth2 client credential flow](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/), for your scenario and the app will be able to make calls to interact with any mailboxes in that tenant. Another choice is to use [EWS Managed API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633710(v=exchg.80).aspx) ,since you get the password of the other user ,you will get the credentials like:

```
  ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
  service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("user_with_access@example.com", "password");
```

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614720/using-ews-api-to-search-through-different-users-mailboxes) for a demo.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable advice.Yes currently I'm using OAuth/ ADAL token cache.My requirement is like I need to send/delete/forward... office 365 mails from my own account and also viewing the o365 mail details for other users from my asp.net application.Should the  OAuth2 client credential flow/ EWS Managed API could fulfill my all requirements? Please suggest me.

Comment: Yes,please check [Outlook Mail REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations)  and [EWS Managed API] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633710(v=exchg.80).aspx)